# Highlight multiple events in CalendarView

Tags: android, android-view, android-calendar

I am trying to display calendar along with events created in my app. I was able to add it to the view.

```
LinearLayout calendarLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarLayout);

CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(mActivity);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
calendarView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2013, 9, 10, 14, 10);

calendarView.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), true, true);

calendarLayout.addView(calendarView);
```

However, I am not able to highlight multiple events. Tried couple of community posts; they did not work quite well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With [MFCalendarView](https://github.com/MustafaFerhan/MFCalendarView), you can highlight multiple events.

```
ArrayList<String> eventDays = new ArrayList<String>();
eventDays.add("2014-02-25");
eventDays.add(Util.getCurrentDate());

mf.setEvents(eventDays);
```

Comment: I have used your library project. Nice work but there is an issue that when I added `eventdays List` and `mf.setEvents(eventDays)` and show the calendar it works fine, but eventually when I change month It is not showing `dots` highlighter as you are using it...